# Suppress Zero value rows

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular

In DAX I have a measure that returns an aggregate of data, some values returned are 0 and I can have my client tool filter for items that are not zero, but how can I force my measure not to return values if the answer is 0?

for example:

> ```
> [Test Measure]:=
> VAR _myMeasure = [MyMeasure]
> Return
> IF (_myMeasure =0, BLANK(),_myMeasure)
> ```

Comment: What is not working with the example you gave?

Comment: my expectation was that when I query the data that uses this measure, that this measure would not return data such as: [Row1] Dim Name, Test Measure (value) [Row2] should be surppressed as it's blank right?, but instead I get a blank value. for [Row 2] Dim Name, Test Measure (Blank).  so maybe I need to do something different?

Comment: Have you tried filtering blanks in the visual level filters?

Comment: do you mean in the client tool? yes, that works, but my users asked if I could remove them from the back end... I started thinking that maybe I could instead create a calculated table that does not return blanks :-/

Comment: found this post from Alberto Ferrari, so I don't think I can do what I want from the tabular side: _[quote]ALLNOBLANKROW serves a different purpose, it removes the optional blank row to fix invalid relationships[/quote]_  [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Use-ALLNOBLANKROW-with-UNION/m-p/256491/highlight/true#M114292)